# Jama API - GET item with tag at the same time

Tags: rest, jama

I need to fetch items from JAMA API, and I do not get the Tag value with the data.
I tried to call GET/{item}/{id} API and then I also need to execute GET/{tags}/{id}/{item} to discover item tag, which takes too much time for multiple items.

Is there any more efficient way to get all data in one API call?

Answer (score 0):

There is the `/items/{id}/tags` endpoint: https://rest.jamasoftware.com/#operation_getTagsOnItem

Answer (score 0):

This can be easy fetched via [py-jama-rest-client](https://jamasoftware-ps.github.io/py-jama-rest-client/py_jama_rest_client/client.html#JamaClient.get_abtract_item_version) library, using `get_items()`. Have a look into the documentation for more such helpful APIs.